# Swift : How can I get time in hours of my current location for my app?

Tags: ios, swift, time, mapkit

I'm currently learning how to implement APIs in iOS apps. Currently I'm writing an app where the app shows current temperature. In the background I want to play GIFs using the time i.e., if the time > 5PM it will show night gif and if time <5PM it will shows sunny gif. My app gets the current location of the user but I don't know how to get time of a particular location. Please help me in the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
```

Comment: Thanks for Clarification! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: Date())
if hours >= 17 {
    // Show night gif
} else {
    // Show sun gif
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Clarification! :D